# Identifier expected when adding to an array

Tags: arrays, list

```
ArrayList<Qubit> cycl = new ArrayList<Qubit>();    
Qubit num0 = new Qubit(4,5,6,64);
cycl.add(num0);
```

has error identifier expected. Can you please help?

Comment: What is `Qubit` here?

Comment: Which statement is getting the error?

Comment: Where does this code come from? Is it part of a method in a class? Can you provide us with a meaningful piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try:

1. Try specifying the type of object to go into the ArrayList: `ArrayList<Qubit> cycl = new ArrayList<Qubit>();`
2. Make sure you are importing `java.util.ArrayList`
3. Make sure you are calling the constructor correctly